# Part of Object Distorts Switching from Edit to Object Mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, object-mode

I'm working on my mesh in edit mode. When I switched to object mode part of my object suddenly shifted. I'm using version 3.6. Any suggestions why this is happening. [image]

The change when I tabbed to Object Mode:

[image]

Comment: You have created shapekeys so the problem probably comes from here but maybe share your file (remove some parts if you want)? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: While preparing the file to send you I deleted several shape keys. It seems to have fixed the problem. What about the shape keys is causing the error?

Comment: It probably comes from the shapekeys but as I don't know exactly what you did it's hard to explain precisely

Comment: I copied several layers and each had several shape keys set. Your suggestion fixed the problem so that's good news. Thanks a bunch. You saved me a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to your shapekeys. When you are in *Edit* mode you'll see the basis shape of your mesh, plus all the changes that you'll do on it within this shapekey. As soon as you'll switch back to *Object* mode, you'll see the other shapekeys influence if their value is not set to 0. This may be the reason here.